# Excel VBA to reverse transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to essentially swap a column with a row of data, but only a certain selection of that row.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
Month    Year Group Min Max
January  2014  A    10 50
January  2014  B    5  75
January  2014  C    25 40
February 2014  A    5  20
February 2014  B    4  8
February 2014  C    22 68
```

I would like to create a new field that collapses Min and Max into a new column called Meausure.  Then transpose group over the value, such that the end result would be:

```
Month    Year Measure  A   B  C
January  2014 Min      10  5  25
January  2014 Max      50  75 40
February 2014 Min      5   4  22
February 2014 Max      20  8  68
```

I find it hard to even explain exactly what the order of operations need to be, so hopefully these tables give enough insight. I have found some other "unpivot" macros, but nothing that seems to work for this type of data structure.

Comment: The order of operations is unpivoting the Min and Max into a measure column and then pivoting the result with Group as a column field. Try using the unpivot code and then using the result to feed a pivot table. Ideally you'll use the unpivoted data as the starting point for all you're analyisis, as it's the most flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running SQL as your need is simply a union of conditional aggregate queries for pivoting. No intricate looping, array objects, etc. required. Assuming you work with PC Excel, using the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files), Excel can run SQL queries on workbooks. Below holds source data in a worksheet called `[MAIN]` and outputs query in worksheet called `[RESULTS]`:

```
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' DB CONNECTION STRING (TWO TYPES SHOWN HERE)'
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    ' SQL STATEMENT '
    strSQL = "SELECT [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year], 'Min' As Type, "
    strSQL = strSQL & " SUM(IIF(Group = 'A', Min, NULL)) AS [A],"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SUM(IIF(Group = 'B', Min, NULL)) AS [B],"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SUM(IIF(Group = 'C', Min, NULL)) AS [C]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [MAIN$]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " "
    strSQL = strSQL & " UNION"
    strSQL = strSQL & " "
    strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year], 'Max' As Type,"
    strSQL = strSQL & "        SUM(IIF(Group = 'A', Max, NULL)) AS [A],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "        SUM(IIF(Group = 'B', Max, NULL)) AS [B],"
    strSQL = strSQL & "        SUM(IIF(Group = 'C', Max, NULL)) AS [C]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [MAIN$]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year]"

    ' OPEN DB AND RECORDSET '
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS '
    i = 0
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' DATA ROWS '
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    ' CLOSE DB AND RECORDSET '
    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Output**

*(as shown group by aggregates order groupings numerically for integer/double and alphabetically for string values, hence February before January and Max before Min -adjust source data as needed)*

```
' Month     Year    Type    A   B   C
' February  2014    Max     20  8   68
' February  2014    Min     5   4   22
' January   2014    Max     50  75  40
' January   2014    Min     10  5   25
```

---

To iterate across many columns employ a `For Each` loop around the SQL query and even consider Jet/ACE SQL's unique [Crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8)!

```
Sub RunAutoSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' DB CONNECTION STRING
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    ' OPEN CONNECTION '
    conn.Open strConnection

    ' LIST ALL NEEDED COLUMNS '
    For Each item In Array("Min", "Max")

        ' SQL STATEMENT
        strSQL = "TRANSFORM Sum([MAIN$]." & item & ") As SumOfMax"
        strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year],'" & item & "' As Type"
        strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [MAIN$]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY [MAIN$].[Month], [MAIN$].[Year]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " PIVOT [MAIN$].Group IN ('A', 'B', 'C')"

        ' OPEN RECORDSET
        rst.Open strSQL, conn

        ' COLUMN HEADERS
        If item = "Min" Then
            i = 0
            Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A1").Activate
            For Each fld In rst.Fields
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
                i = i + 1
            Next fld
        End If

        ' DATA ROWS
        lastrow = Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Worksheets("RESULTS").Rows.Count, _  
                                              "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A" & lastrow + 1).CopyFromRecordset rst

        ' CLOSE RECORDSET '
        rst.Close

    Next item

  ' CLOSE CONNECTION '
  conn.Close 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have two follow up questions, if you wouldn't mind.  In my example I simplified it a little bit and because I am completely new to VBA sorry in advance if these are very simple questions.

In my actual dataset I have something like 15 different columns instead of just a min and max.  I have revised to work for all columns, but is there an easy way to loop this for all columns?

I also have an additional worksheet.  I assume I can just copy over my existing query to also query the additional sheet, does that sound right?

Comment: Use  a `For Each` loop then across a list of 15 columns. in fact, you are in luck as Jet/ACE SQL engine uses the Crosstab query. See extended post at bottom. And yes, you can use additional sheets like any other join table in SQL: `INNER JOIN [OtherWorksheet$] ON...`